# The site would look even nicer with support for Retina displays

Tags: feature-request

While MathJax's support for Retina displays makes Math.SE look even more amazing, one of the unfortunate side effects of upgrading to a Retina display is that the occasional graphic (like the controls used for voting arrows or the site banner) that has not been updated with Retina in mind really stands out.

It would be great if we had an [update that took Retina displays into account](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/SafariImageDeliveryBestPractices/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: How about using the proper name instead of one particular brand name? These are just extra high density pixel displays or XHDPI.

Comment: My interest is in getting it working on a Retina. I don't know about the others (remember: "real problems that you face").

Comment: If I understand correctly, "support for Retina displays" just means "higher resolution images upon request by the browser"?

Comment: [Already requested on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201772/add-high-resolution-graphics-and-or-svg-icons).

Comment: Windows7+DirectWrite+FireFox/IE make fonts also look better (compared with chrome or any browser in windows xp).